# libssl.so.1.0.0 is missing

Tags: 16.04, openssl

while I use the *ccmake*, I got the error message, which is

```
ccmake: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: Error 40
```

*libssl.so.1.0.0* even exists in *lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* but it doesn't work.

I already tried to reinstall that with

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0:amd64
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

The command was worked properly but I don't have an idea where the file was installed and whether it could fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no longer supported and is considered insecure because the default cipher list contains insecure ciphers as mentioned in [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=736687)

Comment: Although this *is* an answer, can you **[edit]** this to include an explanation. Is the reason `libssm1.0.0` consider insecure that it was affected by the Heartbleed bug? Is this for some other reason?